# org-babel call other python block automatically

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have two python blocks. If I execute `blockA`, then execute `blockB`, it works fine. How can I only execute `blockB` without manually executing `blockA`? I am thinking add a `:var from` blockA` but it does not work:

```
#+name blockA
#+begin_src python :session :results output
def funcA():
    print("funcA")
    return
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:

#+name blockB
#+begin_src python :session :results output :var x=blockA
def funcB():
    funcA()
    print("funcB")
    return

funcB()
#+end_src
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing colons after the `#+name`. This works fine:

```org
#+name: blockA
#+begin_src python :session :results output
def funcA():
    print("funcA")
    return
#+end_src

#+name: blockB
#+begin_src python :session :results output :var x=blockA
def funcB():
    funcA()
    print("funcB")
    return

funcB()
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: blockB
: funcA
: funcB
```